# Fixing itemization alignment and line wrap inside tabular

Tags: tables, lists, itemize, enumitem

I'm trying to construct a table using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
 \begin{tabular}{p{.3\linewidth}p{.7\linewidth}}
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{\bf{Time windows and limits:}} \\
  \begin{itemize*}[itemjoin={\newline}]\item soft delivery time windows \emph{(sd)} \end{itemize*} & Time window may be violated, or only a preferred start time of the delivery is provided.\\
  \begin{itemize*}\item hard delivery time windows \emph{(hd)} \end{itemize*} & Deliveries must be made within a defined time window.\\
  \begin{itemize*}\item hard delivery start time \emph{(hs)} \end{itemize*} & Deliveries may not commence before a predefined time.\\
  \begin{itemize*}\item vehicle usage time \emph{(sv)} \end{itemize*} & Vehicles may only be used for a certain amount of time, or may not be available during certain periods, e.g.\ due to maintenance.\\
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{\bf{Instrumentation:}} \\
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{\begin{itemize*}\item For some deliveries, specialized equipment must be present. Either the delivery truck has this equipment, or an additional vehicle must be scheduled. \end{itemize*}}\\
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{\bf{Fleet:}} \\
  \begin{itemize*}\item homogeneous \emph{(ho)} \end{itemize*} & All vehicles are identical.\\
  \begin{itemize*}\item heterogeneous \emph{(he)} \end{itemize*} & Vehicles differ in capacity or equipment carried.\\
 \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image]

As you should notice, there are rooms for improvement:

1. The bullets aren't good. Take for example the first bullet: The beginning of 'dows' should be aligned with the beginning 'soft', not with the bullet.
2. The line underneath 'Instrumentation:' does not respect the table border.

Any additional suggestions to improve the overall look and readability of the table are also warmly welcomed.

**UPDATE**
Based on the excellent answer provided by Gonzalo Medina (see below), I want to add page breaks, i.e. automatically split my table over multiple pages. To do this, I do the following:

1. Include the packages `longtable`, `ltxtable`
2. Put the table in a separate `.tex` file. Replace `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{$\bullet$}c@{\hspace{6pt}}p{.3\linewidth}X}` by `\begin{longtable}{>{$\bullet$}c@{\hspace{6pt}}p{.3\linewidth}X}`. Obviously, change `\end{tablularx}` accordingly.
3. Load the table in the main `.tex` file using `\LTXtable{\linewidth}{table.tex}`

This worked nicely for me. A more elaborate example regarding the usage of `ltxtable` may be found in this [blog](http://blog.eitchnet.ch/?p=6).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use an additional column to automatically include the bullets; this will also give the desired indentation. I also used the `tabularx` package to avoid manual calculation of the column widths, and changed `arraystretch`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{$\bullet$}c@{\hspace{6pt}}p{.3\linewidth}X}
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{\bfseries Time windows and limits:} \\
  & soft delivery time windows \emph{(sd)} & Time window may be violated, or only a preferred start time of the delivery is provided.\\
  & hard delivery time windows \emph{(hd)} & Deliveries must be made within a defined time window.\\
  & hard delivery start time \emph{(hs)} & Deliveries may not commence before a predefined time.\\
  & vehicle usage time \emph{(sv)} & Vehicles may only be used for a certain amount of time, or may not be available during certain periods, e.g.\ due to maintenance.\\
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{\bfseries Instrumentation:} \\
  & \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-23pt\relax}}{For some deliveries, specialized equipment must be present. Either the delivery truck has this equipment, or an additional vehicle must be scheduled.}\\
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries Fleet:} \\
  & homogeneous \emph{(ho)} & All vehicles are identical.\\
  & heterogeneous \emph{(he)} & Vehicles differ in capacity or equipment carried.\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that `\bf` is deprecated, you should use `\bfseries`, instead and they are font switches, not commands receiving arguments.

Comment: Looks great! It took me a bit to analyze your code. I'm still not sure what's the meaning of this: "@{}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-23pt\relax}"

Comment: @user1903852 `@{}` suppresses inter-column space; `\dimexpr` allows calculations with lengths.

Comment: why do you need to specify the width of the column in the first place when defining a \multicolumn? After all, the column sizes are defined immediately after the \begin{tabularx}? I was suspecting something like: & \multicolumn{2}{l}{For some deliveries,...}. Afaik, \multicolumn{i}{..} ensures that a single cell spans the next i columns?

Comment: @user1903852 the `l` type column doesn't allow for text wrapping (that's why the text "For some deliveries..." protruded beyond the left end of the table in your example). If you want text to wrap in a column you need a `p{...}` type column; this remark applies both to the format specification foe the table and also to the second argument of `\multicolumn` (which overrides the format specification).

Answer (score 1):

I have wrapped the `itemize` inside a `minipage`. Also named the list as `xitemize`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newenvironment{xitemize}
     {\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\begin{itemize}\leftskip=-1.5em}
     {\end{itemize}\end{minipage}}

\begin{table}[h]
 \begin{tabular}{p{.3\linewidth}p{.7\linewidth}}
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{\bf{Time windows and limits:}} \\
  \begin{xitemize}\item soft delivery time windows \emph{(sd)} \end{xitemize} & Time window may be violated, or only a preferred start time of the delivery is provided.\\
  \begin{xitemize}\item hard delivery time windows \emph{(hd)} \end{xitemize} & Deliveries must be made within a defined time window.\\
  \begin{xitemize}\item hard delivery start time \emph{(hs)} \end{xitemize} & Deliveries may not commence before a predefined time.\\
  \begin{xitemize}\item vehicle usage time \emph{(sv)} \end{xitemize} & Vehicles may only be used for a certain amount of time, or may not be available during certain periods, e.g.\ due to maintenance.\\
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{\bf{Instrumentation:}} \\
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{\begin{xitemize}\item For some deliveries, specialized equipment must be present. Either the delivery truck has this equipment, or an additional vehicle must be scheduled. \end{xitemize}}\\
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{\bf{Fleet:}} \\
  \begin{xitemize}\item homogeneous \emph{(ho)} \end{xitemize} & All vehicles are identical.\\
  \begin{xitemize}\item heterogeneous \emph{(he)} \end{xitemize} & Vehicles differ in capacity or equipment carried.\\
 \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort! This also works, but isn't as clean as the solution proposed by Gonzalo Medina. 1. there is a lot of white spacing between the words after the bullets (words aren't split into two parts). 2. the right side of the sentence under "Instrumentation:" isn't aligned properly with the right side of the table.

Comment: @Jagath AR: Perhaps you should try a better screen capture software :P .

Comment: @pushpen.paul: Done!